A .NET application crashed in ntdll.dll before the application starts, after the function call NtTestAlert
Application fails to start with the following trace in the dmp file. Used Process monitor but no clue in that also, did not find any result code stating "Access denied" or "Access violation".
ExceptionAddress: fe6d0c8f
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: df250da0
Attempt to read from address df250da0

READ_ADDRESS:  df250da0 
FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
+0
fe6d0c8f ??              ???

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.
EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  df250da0
FAULTING_THREAD:  00000c94

STACK_TEXT:
00000000 00000000 unknown![.ecxr]+0x0
00b7f734 772ba0cc ntdll!NtTestAlert+0x0
00b7f738 77272cff ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x0
00b7f788 772eb304 ntdll!LdrpInitializeInternal+0x0
00b7f7b0 77272a01 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x0

I need to know the cause of the crash, as these functions are not called by the application. Additionally, I would like to know if this is related to the operating system itself.

What you're going to need to do is take a memory dump, read instructions on how to setup AdPlus and you might get the answer you want from DebugDiag otherwise start with a  !analyze in WinDbg.

NtTestAlert is a popular malware injection point. Have you done a virus scan lately?
